# Is there an equivalent to Oracle's user_role_privs view in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, postgresql-9.2

Am trying to fetch information in Postgres equivalent to Oracle's `user_role_privs`.

```
select username,granted_role,admin_option from user_role_privs
```

I tried all the below views in Postgres but couldn't find the desired one

```
information_schema.role_table_grants
pg_roles;
pg_class;
pg_user
pg_catalog.pg_auth_members;
```

Can anyone suggest which view should be used to get `username`, `granted_role` and `admin_option` in Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`pg_auth_members`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-auth-members.html) system catalog that contains relationships between roles (which feature as both users and groups in PostgreSQL).

To get the names of the users and roles, join with the `pg_roles` system catalog.

Comment: i am looking for granted rolename , owner and admin option .From pg_auth_members i get id's

Comment: Oh, I see. I have extended the answer.